# How to check if multiple elements exists

Tags: html, css

Given this html:

```
<div id="wrapper">
     <div id="header-holder">
          <div class="header">header 1</div>
          <div class="header">header 2</div>
     </div>
     <div id="project">project data</div>
</div>
```

I want to apply a style to element in `.header` only if `#project` exists. I'd like to do this with css. Is this possible?

Comment: No, it's not possible with CSS only with this structure.

Comment: use javascript to apply .header $("#project").addClass("header");
but you don't write when you want to apply it, on click, hover or when?

Comment: For a partial explanation of why CSS can't do this, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817792/is-there-a-previous-sibling-css-selector

Comment: Can you apply a class on `#header-holder` on the back end?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trouble with cascading style sheets is they cascade. They go down layer by layer and don't come back up. If your structure were set where your `<div id="project">` was above your `<div id="header-holder">` you could use:

```css
div#wrapper #project + #header-holder .header { ... }
```

However, if you are unable to restructure your HTML, then you'll need to use javascript. If you have access to jQuery you could try the following:

```js
$('#wrapper:has(#project) .header').addClass("has_project");
```

Then in CSS:

```css
.header.has_project{ ... }
```